# How can I hook a subview of a subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, cydia, cydia-substrate

The parent class A has a subview B and that subview has another subview C, this is what i want to hide or apply code to (C)

How ?

B is the third subview of A and C is the second subview of B.

They’re like this:

1. |A
2. ||B “UIView”
3. ||B “UIView”
4. ||B "UIView"
5. |||C
6. |||C (i want to access this)
7. |||C

I already tried

`%hook A`

`-(void)layoutSubviews {`

`for (C *view in subviews[2].subviews)`

`%orig;`

`view.hidden = YES;`

`%end`

but no luck.

Comment: Assuming you're using a storyboard (or xib) to create this structure, put an IBOutlet in your code that connects to C from the class that manages the hierarchy.  (If you're creating the structure some other way, I'd need details of that.)

Comment: Additionally you could register an observer in C and send notifications from anywhere you like. If you only need specific access from a hierarchical view you can work either with an outlet in the storyboard or with a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

The one way I'm thinking of is just doing `subviews[0].subviews[0]...` until you get the view you want. Second if you would have to apply code more than once, I'd recommend that you assign a tag to that view once and then just do [UIView viewWithTag:xx], it's much safer.

But in most cases, at least in my projects, there is a shortcut, like some delegate or reference to that directly. Just show the FlexFlipboard Browser and search through everything.